# Part of shadow disapear in Render. (Smoke domain problem?)

Tags: smoke-simulation, shadows

I get smoke shadow on to my plane until fram nr 149(of 650) Then the yellowed lined box from the smoke(smoke spehre in my smoke domain)goes past my plane/ground. 
Then the shadow disapper from my plane.

Question:
Whats up with that?

Extra info:
On screenshot:
in my 3d mode you can see the bottom yellowed line from the box that followes my smoke downwards untill its supposed to crash with my plane, like a surface. But when the "box" hits the plane, the shadow goes away.

PS. the smoke and the "invisible box goes downwards towards the plane.
I will upload the file to blend-exchange...

if i havent explained my self good enough, let me know

[image]

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2764" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2764/)

this is the blend file